# Embedding Images in Photo frames in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to embed an user-input image in a photo frame (Usually a fancy frame with images)

I believed this can be achieved using css `border-image` property but it does not fit for the photo frames that contains images (like flowers).

Can anyone guide me how to achieve the above ?

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: i suggest you post what you have tried so far

Comment: Watch your wording - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @13ruce1337 I got you. Edited my question

Comment: I'm trying to understand...your trying to make the frame the image (repeating?), not put the image in the frame...

Comment: I found this to be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: But still not sure, whether using `canvas` is the right way or not??? I think it will turn to be tedious to make it as a reusable one